# Cancel QML Transition animation inside GridView on width change

Tags: qt, qml

I have a GridView element that needs to be resized. The problem is, if there is a move transition on the displaced delegates and the width of the GridView changes while the transition animation is in progress, the animating delegates end up in the wrong places. I tried calling complete() on the animation inside the transition when the width of the GridView changes (in order to [jump to the final property values](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-animation.html#complete-method)), but it has no effect. I also tried setting the enabled property of the transition to false and back to true but that does not "cancel" an animation in progress. How might one tell a transition to immediately force all the elements its animating to their destination values?
[image]

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    id: main_window
    width: 1000
    height: 1000
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: grid_container
        width: 500
        height: 280
        color: "yellow"

        GridView {
            id: grid_view
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            cellWidth: grid_view.width / 5
            cellHeight: 70
            model: my_model
            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: grid_view.cellWidth
                height: grid_view.cellHeight
                color: index % 2 ? "red" : "blue"
                border.width: 2
            }
            displaced: Transition {
                NumberAnimation {
                    id: displaced_animation
                    properties: "x,y"
                    duration: 2000
                }
            }

            onWidthChanged: {
                displaced_animation.complete() // Does not work
            }
        }
    }

    Button {
        x: 0
        y: 400
        width: 200
        text: "Model Move Operation"
        onClicked: {
            var model = grid_view.model
            model.move(0, model.count - 1, 1)
        }
    }

    Button {
        x: 250
        y: 400
        width: 200
        text: "Change Grid Width"
        onClicked: {
            grid_container.width = Qt.binding(function(){ return main_window.width})
        }
    }

    ListModel {
        id: my_model
        ListElement {
            letter: "A"
        }
        ListElement {
            letter: "B"
        }
        ListElement {
            letter: "C"
        }
        ListElement {
            letter: "D"
        }
        ListElement {
            letter: "E"
        }
        ListElement {
            letter: "F"
        }
        ListElement {
            letter: "G"
        }
        ListElement {
            letter: "H"
        }
        ListElement {
            letter: "I"
        }
        ListElement {
            letter: "J"
        }
        ListElement {
            letter: "K"
        }
        ListElement {
            letter: "L"
        }
        ListElement {
            letter: "M"
        }
        ListElement {
            letter: "N"
        }
        ListElement {
            letter: "O"
        }
        ListElement {
            letter: "P"
        }
        ListElement {
            letter: "Q"
        }
        ListElement {
            letter: "R"
        }
        ListElement {
            letter: "S"
        }
        ListElement {
            letter: "T"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [Layout attached properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#attached-properties) instead to set a delegate size since you use `GridView`. Use maybe `achors.fill: parent` for `grid_view` instead.

Comment: @folibis Do you mean to size the delegate? My understanding is that the layout attached properties are to be used on Items inside of a layout. Is GridView a layout?

Comment: Right, my apologize for some reason I confused it with GridLayout.